# Why do I have such nightmares with NuGet?

Tags: .net, nuget

I reloaded a project that hasn't been loaded in my solution for some time.  All the assemblies are broken.

[image]

```
me@computer MINGW64 ~/source/repos/MyProject/Source (master)
$ dotnet restore PdfWebTest/
  Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore.
```

```
<Reference Include="Autofac, Version=4.9.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Autofac.4.9.4\lib\net45\Autofac.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

There is definitely Autofac.dll in `Source\packages\Autofac.4.9.4\lib\net45`

If I delete and then reinstall Autofac, it's still broken.

The references in this solution are constantly messing up.  I've actually made scripts before to remove all the references and readd them.  And that has worked sometimes.

Comment: I've had a similar problem and I don't understand exactly why but I can generally "fix" it by closing the solution and deleting all the obj and bin directories.

Comment: We can't see much, but using a .NETCore tool on a project that doesn't target .NETCore at least explains part of the problem

Comment: @HansPassant derp.  Yup.  I also used the `nuget.exe`.  It was already in the solution directory from the last time I had this issue.  Updating the issue.